# Opencart 3 disable date in title

Tags: php, html, opencart, opencart-3, page-title

I have a question about setting up a meta description in Opencart.
For some products, the current date is automatically copied to the meta description.

I tried google, but without effect.

I think there is a problem somewhere in the template, but I don't know exactly.

SEO plugin: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&token=1a815f591c29d028150b050f02915db4&extension_id=16633

thank you for the advice

[image: Image 1]

Answer (score 0):

I think, your template is fine. Little correction, you have an issue with `<title>` tag, not meta description. All you have to check is *SEO Extensions > SEO On-Page Tags Generator*, tab **Product Templates**. Inspect **META TITLE TEMPLATES** for any suspicious templates with *date*. Then on tab **Dashboard** of a current module on **Product Pages: Meta Title** press Generate.

Hope this will help. If no - it's better to receive demo access to your website.